# Pxe over ipv4 returns to bios

Tags: vmware-workstation

I created an server with dhcp and wds.

When i start an empty machine and start over netwok it just says pxe over ipv4.

In the dhcp server it gets an ip adress but the machine just says pxe over ipv4 and doesnt do anything.

Wds and dhcp are on the same server and i think are correctly configured. Because the dhcp server gives out an ip adress.

How can i fix that?

Comment: Are there any messages from Windows bootstrap? Don't you have to press F12 to start PXE boot? Is your platform doing legacy or UEFI PXE boot? And is the server configured for it correctly?

Comment: Hi yes i press f12 and it dhows the same message. I think it starts in uefi.